# How to multiply matching rows from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, data-cleaning

I have two dataframes that looks like this

df1:

[image]
df2:

[image]

So the thing is that I want to multiply the ratio column of df1 with the columns Total, Hombres, Mujeres in df2 when it the column of 'Estado' matches with the column of 'Entidad Federativa in both tables', and when it stops matching it goes to the second row and does the same with the matching columns. Anyone has any idea on his? I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with `level=0` for match first level of `MultiIndex` in `df2` and index values of `Estado`:

```
df1 = df1.rename(index={'Aguascal':'Aguascalientes'})
#if necessary
#df1 = df1.set_index('Estado')

df2 = (df2.replace(',','', regex=True)
          .astype(int)
          .set_index(['Entidad Federativa','Grupo quinquenal de edad']))


df = df2.div(df1['Ratio'], level=0, axis=0)
```

Comment: it says ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Aguascalientes'

Comment: @SebastianNin - what is `print (df1.index[:3])` ?

Comment: It is Index(['Aguascalientes', 'Baja California', 'Baja California Sur'], dtype='object', name='Estado')

Comment: Index(['Entidad federativa', 'Grupo quinquenal de edad', 'Total', 'Hombres',
       'Mujeres'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: @SebastianNin - it means need `.set_index(['Entidad Federativa','Grupo quinquenal de edad'])` for MultiIndex, answer was edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244945/discussion-between-sebastian-nin-and-jezrael).